# Delta Distribution - Alleged Contradiction

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am new to the field of distributions and reading some articles about them. I noticed, that it was written, that every linear bounded functional in $L^p$ can be written as $\displaystyle T(f)=\int f(x)g(x){\mathrm  {d}}x$ with $g\in L^q, 1/p+1/q = 1$. (This follows from the Riesz representation theorem, right?)

Now the compactly supported smooth functions $C_c^\infty(\Omega),\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are a subset of the $p$ integrable ones and on the former, distributions are defined as linear bounded functionals.

It is then mentioned, when introducing the dirac distribution, that this is not a function in the common sense, which is perfectly understandable.

They define it as $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f(x)\delta(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=f(0)$ where $f$ are compactly supported smooth functions.

But since this functional is linear and bounded, and $C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)$ and since the generating function is unique, this would mean, that $\delta$ is a function indeed.

Comment: It's a linear functional on $C_c^\infty$, not on $L^p$.

Comment: But $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$. So if it holds for the latter it has to hold for the former, or not?

Comment: In the $L^p$ topology, $C_c^\infty$ is dense. But distributions are functionals on $C^\infty_c$ that are continuous with respect to the topology given by a collection of seminorms; that is **not** the $L^p$ topology on $C_c^\infty$. In particular $\delta$ is not continuous wrt the $L^p$ topology on $C_x^\infty$.

Comment: So I just mixed up the topologies? I missed that $C_c^\infty$ is endowed with another topology than $L^p$, right?